# Using SAS to transfer data structure

Tags: data-structures, sas, transpose

I have a question on using SAS for data structure transfer. This is my old dataset

```
question answer
1         3
2         4
3         5
4         3
5         1
1         2 
2         4
3         1
4         3
5         6
```

The ideal output dataset is

```
ques1 ques2 ques3 ques4 ques5
3     4     5     3     1
2     4     1     3     6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple. Create a dummy column which stores the questions group and then transpose that data with by variable as that group causing 2 separate output rows. Check out the following code.

```
data have;
infile datalines missover;
input question answer ;
if question=1 then group+1;
datalines;
1         3
2         4
3         5
4         3
5         1
1         2 
2         4
3         1
4         3
5         6
;;;;
run;
proc transpose data=have out=want prefix=ques;
by group;
var answer;
id question;
run;
proc print data=want;run;
```